# Another unnamed CacheManager already exists when using Hibernate L2 ehcache and spring boot enabledCache

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, ehcache, hibernate-cache

I have an application that have more than 100 domain model i want to integrate ehcache and hibernate L2cache ,my application used ehcache for cache some of service s methods . my CacheConfiguration is like this

```
 package org.roshan.framework.config;

import org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheConfigurationBuilder;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.ResourcePoolsBuilder;
import org.ehcache.expiry.Duration;
import org.ehcache.expiry.Expirations;
import org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107Configuration;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureAfter;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.JCacheManagerCustomizer;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@AutoConfigureAfter(value = {DatabaseConfiguration.class})
public class CacheConfiguration {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CacheConfiguration.class);
    private final javax.cache.configuration.Configuration<Object, Object> jcacheConfiguration;


    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        log.info("Remove Cache Manager metrics");
        log.info("Closing Cache Manager");
    }

    public CacheConfiguration(JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {
        JHipsterProperties.Cache.Ehcache ehcache = jHipsterProperties.getCache().getEhcache();

        jcacheConfiguration = Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(
                CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Object.class, Object.class,
                        ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(ehcache.getMaxEntries()))
                        .withExpiry(Expirations.timeToLiveExpiration(Duration.of(ehcache.getTimeToLiveSeconds(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                        .build()
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public JCacheManagerCustomizer cacheManagerCustomizer() {
        log.debug("Starting Ehcache");

        return cm -> {
            // some cache for using in method of service
            cm.createCache("baseInfoCache", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache("attachments", jcacheConfiguration);
        };
    }

}
```

in application.yml change hibernate cache config like this

```
spring:
    devtools:
        restart:
            enabled: true
        livereload:
            enabled: true # we use gulp + BrowserSync for livereload
    application:
        name: roshanframework
    jpa:
        open-in-view: true
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: none
        properties:
              hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
              hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
              hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
              hibernate.generate_statistics: false
              hibernate.dialect : org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
              #hibernate.default_schema : ihsl
              hibernate.show_sql : true
              hibernate.current_session_context_class:  org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

but when i start my application i get exception that i have 2 cachemanager how solve this problem .

```
The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory.start(EhCacheRegionFactory.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory.start(RegionFactory.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.<init>(CacheImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name.
The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.assertNoCacheManagerExistsWithSameName(CacheManager.java:626)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:391)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory.start(EhCacheRegionFactory.java:69)
    ... 51 common frames omitted
```

I dont know why two cache manager exist? how can change configuration to using one cache manager for both hibernate and methods?

Comment: I would check whether another CacheManager is autoconfigured. Spring Boot auto configures based on what is present on the classpath and sometimes this is not what you want. Not sure whether this applies for your case, but worth checking out. Also, you should be able to get around the problem by using @Qualifier on your beans since there seems to be a naming conflict.

Comment: i dont use cache manager direct ,hibernate and spring used cache manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also ran into this problem recently.
Soln is to use "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" as hibernate factory_class.

```
spring:
    jpa:
      properties:
        hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
```